# High school level question of two quadratic equations sharing a common root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, discriminant

The quadratic equation is
$$
(a^2+b^2)x^2 - 2b(a+c)x + (b^2+c^2) = 0
$$
$a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-zero, real and distinct numbers.
This equation has non-zero real roots $(D \geq 0)$.
One of the roots of the above equation is also the root of which equation from the following:

A) $$(b^2-c^2)x^2 + 2a(b-c)x - (a^2) = 0$$
B) $$(b^2+c^2)x^2 - 2a(b+c)x + (a^2) = 0$$
C) $$(a^2)x^2 + a(c-b)x - (bc)=0$$
D) $$(a^2)x^2 - a(b-c)x + (bc)=0$$

Using $D \geq 0$, I got $b^2=ac$, and substituting the value of $b^2$ in the original equation, I get :
$$ax^2 - 2bx + c = 0$$

How should I proceed further?

Comment: The given equation can be written as:
$$(ax-b)^2+(bx-c)^2=0.$$
Thus $x=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$. Now you can C) :-)  if $b/a$ is a root of any of these.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnuragA !

Comment: @DavidK: Opening the brackets and simplifying further, you'll end up with $$(b^2-ac)^2 ≤ 0$$ And since it cannot be less than 0, you will get $$b^2=ac$$

Comment: I see. I mistakenly assumed you had derived the equation $b^2=ac$ as directly as you stated; yes, it works with a few intermediate steps ($D=-4(b^2 - ac)^2$, hence $D\geq0\implies(b^2-ac)^2\leq 0$ as you observed). The conclusion was never in doubt, anyway, since from the first comment we must have $b^2 = ac$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to the fine method given in the comments, as you noticed the determinant for the given equation is

$$\Delta =-4(ac-b^2)^2 \ge 0 \implies b^2=ac$$

which leads to

$$(a+c)(ax^2-2\sqrt{ac}x+c)=0 \implies ax^2-2\sqrt{ac}x+c=0 \implies (\sqrt a x-\sqrt c)^2=0$$

that is $$x=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}=\frac b a=\frac c b$$

from which we see that only case *C* is compatible.

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. I appreciate the objective approach to this question!

Comment: This is a good method for multiple answer question if we are not requested for a full discussion. Using a concrete case can give some useful insight or also the correct answer.

Comment: But, I still have one doubt remaining, if you please. Using WLOG, can we ignore the fact that a, b and c are distinct non-zero numbers?

Comment: @DivyanshKalra Sorry! I've lost the "distinct" part...I try to fix that!

Comment: Actually, $a=1-\varepsilon$, $b=1$, $c=1+\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon\neq0$ results in an equation with a negative discriminant and no real roots. The numbers must be in geometric progression, not arithmetic, in order for there to be real roots.

Comment: @DavidK Good catch thanks, I didn’t notice that at all. I fix that point.

Comment: @DavidK I didn't realize at first that is always $\Delta=0$, therefore my first idea doesn't work. I've carried out the solution following the first idea by the OP.

Comment: I get $x=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}$. But I don't understand how this also equals $=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$. Aren't $a,b,c$ non-zero, real and distinct numbers?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson We have $$x=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt c}=\frac{ c}{\sqrt {ac}}=\frac c b$$ and $$x=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a}\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt a}=\frac{ \sqrt{ac}}{a}=\frac b a$$

Comment: Wow I never thought about it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Using $\,D \geq 0\,$, I got $\,b^2=ac\,$

Given this is as a multiple choice question, it is enough to check particular cases for elimination, and it turns out that it's enough to check one case here. The smallest distinct, positive integers satisfying $b^2=ac$ are $a=1,b=2,c=4$. In that case the original equation has the double root $\,x=2\,$, and the only given choice that has $\,2\,$ as a root is $\,C\,$, so the answer must be $\,C\,$.

$$
\begin{matrix}
& & a=1,b=2,c=4
\\ &(a^2+b^2)x^2 - 2b(a+c)x + (b^2+c^2) = 0 & 5 x^2 - 20 x + 20 = \color{red}{5 (x - 2)^2 = 0}
\\ A) &(b^2-c^2)x^2 + 2a(b-c)x - a^2 = 0 & -12 x^2 - 4 x - 1 = 0
\\ B) &(b^2+c^2)x^2 - 2a(b+c)x + a^2 = 0 & 20 x^2 - 12 x + 1 = 0
\\ \color{red}{C)} &a^2x^2 + a(c-b)x - bc = 0 & x^2 + 2 x - 8 =
\color{red}{(x-2)(x+4) = 0}
\\ D) &a^2x^2 - a(b-c)x + bc = 0 & x^2 + 2 x + 8 = 0
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have some good answers already (one is just a comment but should probably have been an answer). Here's a slightly different path to the solution.

Once you have found that $b^2 = ac$ as observed in the question,
you know that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are in geometric progression.
So write $b = ar$ and $c = ar^2$. Making these substitutions in the original equation,

$$ (a^2+a^2r^2)x^2 - 2ar(a+ar^2)x + (a^2r^2+a^2r^4) = 0. $$

Since $a \neq 0$ we can divide all terms by $a^2$:

$$ (1+r^2)x^2 - 2r(1+r^2)x + (r^2+r^4) = 0. $$

Since $1 + r^2 \neq 0$ we can divide by $1 + r^2$:

$$ x^2 - 2rx + r^2 = 0. $$

This equation has a double root, $x = r$.
That is, as in the other answers, $x = \dfrac ba = \dfrac cb$,
and only C can be true.